# Positive divergence on a torus

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Today my teacher told that there no exists any function defined on a torus with positive divergence. She told this as it was a very simple fact, but I don't figure out where this come from.  Could someone give me any hint?

Comment: It's because the total integral of the divergence must be zero.

Comment: I tried to use the divergence theorem and I obtain  $\int_{\partial T} f\cdot dn$, but I don't see why this has to be zero.

Comment: The torus has no boundary: $\partial T = \varnothing$, hence the integral must vanish.

Comment: Exactly. There's nothing special about the torus. Any compact manifold without boundary would give the same result